# Motorcycle Velocity Word Problem using Intergrals

Tags: calculus, integration

A motorcycle, starting from rest, speeds up with a constant acceleration of 2.6m/s2. After it has travelled 120m, it slows down with a constant acceleration of −1.5m/s2 until it attains a speed of 12m/s. What is the distance travelled by the motorcycle at that point?

I have set up the info as follows:

$
t=0\\
a(0)=2.6m/s\\
v(0)=0 \\
s(0)=0\\
$

$
t=t_1\\
a(t_1)=-1.5 m/s\\
v(t_1)=?\\
s(t_1)=120m\\
$

$
t=t_f\\
v(t_f)=12m/s\\
s(t_f)=n
$

So,

$
a(t)=2.6m/s\\
s(t) \rightarrow \frac{2.6t^2}{2}=120 \rightarrow t=\sqrt \frac{240}{2.6} \\
v(t) \rightarrow 2.6t \rightarrow 4\sqrt{39} \approx 24.97 \\
$

At this point I am stuck.
I am guessing my next step is to use $v(t_f)-v(t_1) \int a dt$.

But don't understand how to apply it to find $s(t_f)=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(t_2) = v(t_1) + a t_2$

i.e $12 = 24.98 - 1.5t_2 \implies t_2 \approx 8.65$

(please note the total time is $t_f = t_1 + t_2)$.

Distance traveled in time $\displaystyle t_2, s_2 = \int_0^{t_2} (24.98 - 1.5t)dt = 24.98t_2 - 0.75{t_2}^2$

Now calculate $s_2$. Total distance traveled $ = s_1 + s_2 = 120 + s_2\,$.

Comment: Thank-you - I  know the answer should be s= 120+160=280. Should t2 be 8.653?

Comment: Yes indeed. Good catch!